# How do I filter through Django models that are not yet saved in DB?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-models

Here is my model class and a function. I would only like to add new animals to my list.

```
class Animals(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'animals'


animals = []
for name in ['duck', 'cow', 'cat', 'dog']:
    if (THIS ALREADY EXISTS) animals.objects.filter(name=name): # This will throw an error, because its a list
        continue
   else:
        animal = Animals(name=name)
        animals.append(animal)
```

Keep in mind I do not want to save these models to the database yet, but it would be great to query my list of models stored in memory as if they were all saved as a database table.

Comment: Models are meant for *storing data into DB*,

Comment: Eventually they will be stored in DB, but there is more I want to do to them. For now should I just loop through all the animals?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont understand your logic. Can you make it clear ?

Comment: I guess I'm asking what is the most efficient way to confirm animal with animal_name is not already included in my list?

Comment: What I understood is, you need to add new animals to the DB if it's not in DB. Right ?

Comment: One more thing: According to naming convention, You shouldn't name model object "Animals" , prefer to name it "Animal" - remove pluralize.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over list of animals and do anything with them.

but be aware of all instances not saved in database have no pk attribute

but you can not filter them by model query

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Please use .exists()

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'dragon', 'bear']
new_animals = []
for animal in animals:
   if Animals.objects.filter(name=animal).exists():
      continue
   else:
      new_animal = Animal(name=animal)
      new_animals.append(new_animal)
```

or briefly:

```
new_animals = [Animals(name=animal) for animal in animals if not Animals.objects.filter(name=animal).exists()]
```